# How can I automatically turn off track monitoring during playback?

Tags: cubase

In Cubase 7.5 (Artist), I often have a few inserts on my channels while recording, e.g. a reverb for a singer, or a compressor on an acoustic guitar.

[image]

But when I track short passages that I want to play back immediately, I always have to manually turn off monitoring on that track to be able to hear something.

Another example: when I want a singer to punch into the track directly after an existing phrase, and they want to hear that phrase, I have to turn on monitoring immediately before the recording starts. This is tedious.

Can I set Cubase to turn off monitoring for a given track, or even all tracks, during playback? I haven't found a setting for this. Or is there another more straightforward way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cubase has such an automatic setting…

*Prefs > VST > Auto Monitoring > Manual, Record Enable, Record Running* or *Tape Machine Style*.

...though personally I just monitor the direct from the preamp [no latency, plus I have some comp & rev on the preamp that doesn't go to track] & the playback from the channel.

Essentially, I use Cubase's Lane facility for multiple takes, or just throw every take on a new track & don't bother listening to playback on a line by line basis, just do multiple full takes & comp it all later. Depends on how you prefer to work.

Comment: Yeah, I'd love to have a separate preamp for things like this but DAW will have to do for the moment :) I usually prefer full takes too, but it's tedious to work with that if you do, say, a guitar solo and use a Guitar Amp plugin for everything.

Comment: I do tend to do the same even for guitar - but I've been known to vary routine, possibly depending on mood rather than any logic... Use hardware amp-sim; record clean with plugin amp on output channel, or [least popular] put amp-sim on input & record the amped sound.

Answer (score 1):

OK I don't know Cubase but one way to resolve this is to use one channel for monitoring for the singer which always stays on, while arming a different track to record the same input and leaving monitoring off on that track so you can hear the recorded regions immediately.  Just an idea.  Ableton Live which I use is apparently not the most professional recording software but not only does this trick work, there is an "Auto" setting per track wherein it will monitor when recording but playback when the session is playing back.

Comment: Seems like a viable alternative—let me check that later.

Comment: Cubase has a similar auto setting, though personally I just monitor the direct from the preamp [no latency, plus I have some comp & rev on the preamp that doesn't go to track] & the playback from the channel. Essentially, I use Cubase's Lane facility for multiple takes, or just throw every take on a new track & don't bother listening to playback on a line by line basis, just do multiple full takes & comp it all later. Depends on how you prefer to work.

Comment: Prefs > VST > Auto Monitoring [that's in the full version, I've never used Artist] Manual, Record Enable, Record Running, or Tape Machine Style.

Comment: @slhck - apologies. I'd assumed as OP you'd get notifications on all additions to the thread. I re-jigged it all slightly into an answer.